# Extracting m3u8 link location with python from scraped links

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, m3u8

I'm working at a python script which is scraping the sitemap.xml from a website, it's taking the links and then is parsing every link.
The scraper is checking if a og:video tag exist in the header, If og:video is present, is accessing the link and extract the m3u8 link.
The issue is that the script is not able to load m3u8 location. I really appreciate your help in this project.
Code:

```
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Read the sitemap XML file
response = requests.get('https://www.webcamromania.ro/post-sitemap.xml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml')

# Extract the links from the sitemap
links = []
for loc in soup.find_all('loc'):
    link = loc.text
    if not any(link.endswith(ext) for ext in ['.jpg', '.png']):
        links.append(link)

# Create a CSV file to store the data

with open('C:/Users/USER/Desktop/data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['link', 'title', 'description', 'og_image', 'og_video', 'm3u8']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

# Iterate over the links and extract the data
for link in links[155:161]:
    driver.get(link)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    # Extract the title and description
    title = soup.find('title').text
    description = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'description'})['content']


    # Write the data to the CSV file
    with open('C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/data.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow({'link': link, 'title': title, 'description': description, 'og_image': og_image, 'og_video': og_video, 'm3u8': m3u8})

# Close the webdriver
driver.close()
```

to be able to extract the m3u8 link location

Comment: Can you add the error message you are getting?

Comment: Hi @TheSoldier, there are no error messages, I can't extract the m3u8 link.